# How do I select child elements of any depth using XPath?

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have this (simplified):

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- some input fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="proceed"/>
</form>
```

Then I can select the submit button by XPath `//form[@id='myform']/input[@type='submit']`. Great.

However, my templates might change and I want to be flexible in the depth in which the submit button is located. It might be put in a table, like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- some input fields -->
    <table><tr><td>
           <input type="submit" value="proceed"/>
    </td></tr></table>
</form>
```

I know I can select elements which are grandchildren, but I can't select grand-grand-grand-...-childeren of any depth. E.g.:

- `//form[@id='myform']/*/input[@type='submit']` only selects grand-children, no further depths.
- `//form[@id='myform']/*/*/input[@type='submit']` only selects grand-grand-children, no further or less depths.
- `//form[@id='myform']/**/input[@type='submit']` is not valid.

So, how do I select this submit button reliably without using element IDs?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You're almost there. Simply use:

```
//form[@id='myform']//input[@type='submit']
```

The `//` shortcut can also be used inside an expression.

Comment: C# doesn't seem to understand this notation. `//form//input` returns null in C# while Chrome can find 35 inputs using the same xpath

Comment: My last comment is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232671/xpath-selects-in-htmlagilitypack-dont-work-as-expected

Comment: Check out this site for more XPath commands - https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/08/xpath-axes.html/

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the XmlDocument and XmlNode.

Say:

```
XmlNode f = root.SelectSingleNode("//form[@id='myform']");
```

Use:

```
XmlNode s = f.SelectSingleNode(".//input[@type='submit']");
```

It depends on the tool that you use. But .// will select any child, any depth from a reference node.

Comment: Works well within Powershell using SelectSingleNode command on a certain XML node extracted earlier.

Answer (score 13):

```
//form/descendant::input[@type='submit']
```

Comment: add some description to it.