# Xpath: select div that contains class AND whose specific child element contains text

Tags: xpath

With the help of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503721/xpath-find-a-node-whose-class-attribute-matches-a-value-and-whose-text-contains) I have an almost working xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and contains(., 'someText')]
```

However this gets two `divs`: in one it's the child `td` that has someText, the other it's child `span`.

How do I narrow it down to the one with the `span`?

```
<div class="measure-tab">
  <!-- table html omitted -->
  <td> someText</td>
</div>

<div class="measure-tab">  <-- I want to select this div (and use contains @class)
  <div>
    <span> someText</span>  <-- that contains a deeply nested span with this text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YOu need to post input xml atleast a part of what you want to write xpath for ?

Comment: Do you mean `...and contains(span, 'someText')]`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but then I get "no matching nodes" in FirePath validator

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - Close. It would be ` and contains(div/span, 'someText')]`

Comment: Yes, seeing the example it would be div/span

Answer (score 154, accepted):

To find a `div` of a certain class that contains a `span` [at any depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016521/how-do-i-select-child-elements-of-any-depth-using-xpath/16016587#16016587) containing certain text, try:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and contains(.//span, 'someText')]
```

That said, this solution looks extremely fragile. If the table happens to contain a `span` with the text you're looking for, the `div` containing the table will be matched, too. I'd suggest to find a more robust way of filtering the elements. For example by using IDs or top-level document structure.

Comment: Screen-scraping is always by its nature pretty fragile.

Comment: is there any way to select an element whose child's class contains specific text?

Comment: @oldboy: //button[contains(text(), "11") and contains(@class, "MuiPickersDay-day") and .//span[contains(@class, "Mui")]]

Comment: @Andy thx hopefully it will help somebody out in the future

Answer (score 26):

You can use `ancestor`.  I find that this is easier to read because the element you are actually selecting is at the end of the path.

```
//span[contains(text(),'someText')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab')]
```

Comment: More info on "axes" (of which ancestor is one): https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 21):

You could use the xpath :

`//div[@class="measure-tab" and .//span[contains(., "someText")]]`

Input :

```
<root>
<div class="measure-tab">
  <td> someText</td>
</div>
<div class="measure-tab">
  <div>
    <div2>
       <span>someText2</span>
   </div2>
  </div>
</div>
</root>
```

Output :

```
    Element='<div class="measure-tab">
  <div>
    <div2>
      <span>someText2</span>
    </div2>
  </div>
</div>'
```

Comment: That would select the span and not the div.

Comment: I thought OP wanted `span`

Comment: I tried to make it as explicit as possible with the <-- comment :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change your second condition to check only the span element:

```
...and contains(div/span, 'someText')]
```

If the span isn't always inside another div you can also use

```
...and contains(.//span, 'someText')]
```

This searches for the span anywhere inside the div.

Comment: Accepting nwellnhof's answer as he got it first, but +1 for the alternative. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way:

```
//div[contains(text(),'someText')][@class='measure-tab']
```

This `XPath` expression will select all `div` elements in the DOM that contain the text 'someText' and have a `class` attribute with the value 'measure-tab'.