# Parsing Socialblade Information using Xpath and importing it into Google Sheets

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am trying to build a Youtube analysis template to monitor my channel's competition.

I would like to parse certain information from Socialblade, but I have just managed to get the information which has an  name. The image below shows the **xpath** for Number of channel uploads:

[image: Data has associated id]

[image: Channel's uploads]

However, when I try to get information that doesn't have an  associated to it I can't seem to be able to extract that information.

[image: The data has no id]

I have tried changing the **xpath** that Chrome generates automatically but had no success. Here's the original xpath for the **Date of creation**, which is the information I would like to import into Google Sheets:

[image]

When I insert this on Google Sheets I get an error message saying that there is a formula parse error.

How can I retrieve this information from SB's website and import it into Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the appropriate XPath :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//span[.='User Created']/following-sibling::span")
```

[image: SB]

Comment: Could you share the code to get the profile picture as well? I have used the following code but while it doesn't result in an erorr it doesn't retrieve the image from the src. 

=IMPORTXML(D2,"//img[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoAvatar']")

Any idea how to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: For this you want the `src` attribute, in your xpath query, that's the image's url. Whith which you can import it into sheets. I've edited my answer to add this example.

Comment: Use `=IMAGE(IMPORTXML(A1;"//img[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoAvatar']/@src"))`. https://framapic.org/hyZm7QL3N2h3/JjOH08mAyB5K.PNG

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942850/xpath-select-div-that-contains-class-and-whose-specific-child-element-contains/38943029) helps.

Also you appear to be concatenating wrong. Use single quotes like so:

> `=IMPORTXML(D2, "//span[.='User Created']/following-sibling::span")`

---

If you want to **get the url of an image**, you can do so by fetching the `"src"` attribute of the image like:

> `=IMPORTXML("website-url", "//img[@id='image-tag-id']/@attribute-value-you-want")`

Where you replace the parameters in the formula with real ones.

---

Then, if you would like to **embed the image into the sheet**, use:

> `=IMAGE(IMPORTXML("profile-url", "//img[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoAvatar']/@src"))`

### and replace url with the user's profile url you want.

**References:**

- [Following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling)
- [Axes X-Path specs.](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#axes)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems not to retrieve any results. I still got the same error.

Comment: Can you share the error, is it parse error, or empty content from the response?

Comment: It does seem to work now. I tried yesterday several times but it wouldn't work. Any ideas as to what code to use to retrieve the profile picture? I left a comment in the other response with the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.