# Select a div for a specific class which has child elements that contains a certain text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Given this html sample :

```
<div class="measure-tab"> --- i want to select this one
  <span class="color_title">someText</span>
</div>
<div class="measure-tab"> --- i dont want to select this one
  <span class="color_title">someText</span>
  <div>
      <span class="qwery">jokerText</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="measure-tab"> --- i want to select this one
  <span class="color_title">someText</span>
</div>
```

I want to select the div that has @class='measure-tab' which has under it a span that as a specific class and text = someText and a nested span that has a specific class and does not contain text = 'jokerText', all this in an XPATH

What i've tried is :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and //span[@class="color_title" and (contains(text(),'someText')) and //span[@class="color_title" and not(contains(text(),'jokerText'))]]
```

But this dosen't seem to work.
I also used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942850/xpath-select-div-that-contains-class-and-whose-specific-child-element-contains) post as inspiration.

EDIT : Corrected bad description of what is the goal for this question

EDIT, made a new solution :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and //span[contains(@class, 'color_title') and //span[not(contains(@class, 'qwery'))]]]
```

But this returns all the divs, instead of not matching it with  --- i dont want to select this one

```
<span class="color_title">someText</span>
  <div>
      <span class="qwery">jokerText</span>
  </div>
```

I feel so close but yet so far, haha, it dosen't make sense for me why is it matching it with `<span class="qwery">jokerText</span>` when i wrote not contains there

Comment: Does the bellow answers has solved your issue? if yes, please feel free to accept the correct answer with click icon `√`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for-

```
MyDivs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='measure-tab' and not(descendant::*[text() = 'jokerText' and @class = 'qwery'])]")
```

This will select all the `div` tag which does not have `jokerText` in it.

Comment: Yeah, but won't this select the div that has `<span class="qwery">jokerText</span>` also?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but, it really gets messy with many other similar stuff, so I really wanna fiter it via xpath, thanks for the effort, if nobody else can help with this i might aswell pick ur answer

Comment: I also edited the post with a new solution looking only by tag attributes, but it seems that not contains dosen't do what I hoped it did, which was to not get the div that has the attr `@class="qwery"`

Comment: I have changed my code and tried that all your requirements met, Hope it works :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can query with **`not(following-sibling::div/span.....)`**

Try with following xpath:

```
//span[@class='color_title' and not(following-sibling::div/span[@class='qwery' and text()='jokerText'])]/parent::div[@class='measure-tab']
```