# Xpath in R for element that contains target text itself or in any of their children

Tags: r, xpath

I want to find the element that contains the target text itself or in any of their children.

**Sample data:**

```
library(magrittr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)    
html <- "<button><span><span>as</span></span></button><button><p>ds</p></button><input><span><span>as</span></span><input>"
doc <- html %>% read_html()
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[self::button and //*[contains(text(), 'as')]]")
```

Please consider that my original data is more complex, i check for 10+ strings that could be within the target Elements. Therefore, i would prefer using "//*[self::button or self::Input]" instead of "//button",...
Moreover, the target text could be within the target element (button or Input) itself or in any of the children.

**Desired Output:**

First button and the input

**What i tried:**

```
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[(self::button or self::input) and //*[contains(text(), 'as')]]")
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[(self::button or self::input)]//*[contains(text(), 'as')]")
```

see [How do I select child elements of any depth using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016521/how-do-i-select-child-elements-of-any-depth-using-xpath)

Comment: Can you please share the output you are getting from these commands as well as the output you would like to be getting (ie what's wrong with these versions specifically)?

Comment: I think the problem is that the HTML tag `<input>` is a void element. It cannot contain child elements. Basically that's invalid syntax. You can see the structure with `html_structure(doc)`. The `input` node does not "contain" the "as" text. The parser moves the span into a sibling node, not a child node.

Comment: thanks my example is bad, let me find a better one.

Comment: actually i think your info actually solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your expressions is that they use an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) instead of a [relative location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-RelativeLocationPath). An example that preserves your style:

```
//*[(self::button or self::input) and .//*[contains(text(), 'as')]]
```

More in the XPath style:

```
//*[self::button|self::input][.//text()[contains(.,'as')]]
```

Test it [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/732adca723223f64e4d09b6c3c7cfbda)