# How to find links children of any level

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

I have the following piece of html inside a page I loaded using puppeteer and I'm trying to get all the child links (not just direct children, child `a`s at any level).

```
<ul class="ptf">
    <li class="pti">
        <div data-testid="pagetree-item-expander" class="pe" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false"></div>
       <a href="/jsw/docs/start” data-testid="atlas_link">kl</a>
       <ul class="ptf" style="display:none">
            <li class="pti">
                <a href="/jsw/docs/what/" data-testid="atlas_link">ij</a>
            </li>
            <li class="pti">
                <a href="/jsw/docs/where/" data-testid="atlas_link">gh</a>
            </li>
            <li class="pti">
                <a href="/jsw/docs/common/" data-testid="atlas_link">ef</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
     <li class="pti">
         <div data-testid="pagetree-item-expander" class="pe" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false"></div>
       <a href="/jsw/docs/ge/" data-testid="atlas_link">cd</a>
       <ul class="ptf" style="display:none">
            <li class="pti">
                <a href="/jsw/docs/wha/" data-testid="atlas_link">ab</a>
            </li>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I tried the following but it's not listing down any children. What am I doing wrong?

```
const links = await page.$x("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div[2]/div/li[5]/ul//a");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    
    const textContent = await links[i].getProperty("href");
    const srcText = await textContent.jsonValue();
    console.log(srcText);
  }
```

Context: I'm looking to get URLs of all child links within this link:
[image]

Expected outcome: A flat array with the following first 10 URLs:

```
[“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/get-started-with-advanced-roadmaps/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/what-is-advanced-roadmaps/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/where-do-i-find-advanced-roadmaps/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/common-jira-software-configurations-for-advanced-roadmaps/“, “https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-a-sample-advanced-roadmaps-plan/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-a-new-plan-in-advanced-roadmaps/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-do-i-navigate-advanced-roadmaps/“, 
“https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/change-your-advanced-roadmaps-plan-settings/“, “https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-do-i-read-my-advanced-roadmaps-plan/“, “https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/what-do-the-symbols-in-advanced-roadmaps-mean/“]
```

Comment: You just want all `href`s? `await page.$$eval("a[href]", els => els.map(el => el.href))`? I'd suggest avoiding ElementHandles and XPath unless you really need them and I'd watch out for those [overly-rigid paths](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) in general, especially here since they're the opposite of "at any level".

Comment: Apparently that returns all links. How can I get only the child links inside `//*[@id=\"root\"]/div[2]/div/li[5]/ul`?

Comment: Could you provide the page you're working with and describe the logic behind the data you want? That's almost certainly not a good path to use. If even a single parent in that chain changes unexpectedly, it breaks. You can append `//a` to dip deeply in the XPath ([How do I select child elements of any depth using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016521/how-do-i-select-child-elements-of-any-depth-using-xpath)), but I suggest providing more context instead to avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: @ggorlen Context: I'm writing a web scraper to extract some documentation. But I only want docs of a sub-topic (hence the need to find children of a specific element). I only want docs related to Advanced Roadmaps and the page I'm working with: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/plan-and-view-cross-project-work-with-advanced-roadmaps/

Comment: Actually, there is an expander button on the top left next to the breadcrumbs that show all the docs under the "Plan and view cross-project work with Advanced Roadmaps" (Roughly 150 docs). The expected output is a list of URLs of those child docs.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: A flat array. I've updated the question with the first 10 URLs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an XY problem. The data is in the page source as a JSON string, so you can get it [without any dependencies](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate) or imports by using Node 18's native `fetch`:

```js
fetch("<Your URL>")
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const pageTree = JSON.parse(
      html.match(/^ *pageTree: (.*);*$/m)[1]
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(pageTree, null, 2));
    const hrefs = pageTree
      .find(({title}) =>
        title.toLowerCase().includes("advanced roadmaps")
      )
      .childList[0].childList.map(({slug}) => slug);
    console.log(hrefs);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Output:

```
<giant JSON structure with the entire nav tree>
[
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/what-is-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/where-do-i-find-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/common-jira-software-configurations-for-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-a-sample-advanced-roadmaps-plan/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-a-new-plan-in-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-do-i-navigate-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/change-your-advanced-roadmaps-plan-settings/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-do-i-read-my-advanced-roadmaps-plan/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/what-do-the-symbols-in-advanced-roadmaps-mean/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/what-keyboard-shortcuts-are-available-in-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/add-teams-and-releases-to-your-advanced-roadmaps-plan/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/build-out-your-plan-in-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/planning-tools-in-advanced-roadmaps/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-different-views-of-your-advanced-roadmaps-plan/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-ted-uses-advanced-roadmaps-scenarios-and-capacity/',
  '/jira-software-cloud/docs/how-veronica-uses-advanced-roadmaps-cross-project-planning/'
]
```

This runs in a fraction of the time Puppeteer would take, 0.879s on my decade-old laptop. Although it's possible the JSON format could change at any time, it's just as likely that the DOM could as well.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878732/6243352) for a detailed walkthrough of how to find your data like this. It's written in Python but all of the concepts apply to Node.

If your requests are being blocked (and you added a user agent header), or for some reason you *really* want/need to use Puppeteer, the data in question is attached to the window, so you can use:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^20.2.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.url().replace(/\/$/, "") === url.replace(/\/$/, "")
      ? req.continue()
      : req.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const hrefs = await page.evaluate(() =>
    window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__.pageTree
      .at(-1)
      .childList[0].childList.map(({slug}) => slug)
  );
  console.log(hrefs);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

This took 3-4x as long to run as the `fetch` version for me.

Comment: I did this small change to list "all" children
```
        const a = pageTree
            .find(({title}) =>
                title.toLowerCase().includes("parenttitle")
            ).childList;

        const links = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          links.push(a[i].slug);
          if(typeof a[i].childList !== "undefined"){
            const grandchildren = a[i].childList;
            for (let j = 0; j < grandchildren.length; j++) {
              links.push(grandchildren[j].slug);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: How about `a.flatMap(e => [e.slug, ...e.childList.map(e => e.slug)])`?